# change data point value inside load event in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts, updating

In a HighCharts chart, I need to change a data point inside the chart object. So I use the events property. But the following toy code does not work:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            events: {
                load: function () {
         this.series[0].data[1].y=7.5;
         this.redraw();
                }
            },
        },
        series: [{type: 'scatter',
                  data:[
                    {y:10,x:1},
                    {y:8,x:2},
                    {y:9,x:3},
                    {y:7,x:4},
                    {y:7,x:5},
                        ]
                }]
    });
});
```

What's wrong?
Jfiddle version here: http://jsfiddle.net/zqhavLz9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use `this.series[0].update`:

```
this.series[0].update({
                    data: [
                        {y:10,x:1},
                        {y:7.5,x:2},
                        {y:9,x:3},
                        {y:7,x:4},
                        {y:7,x:5},
                    ]
                });
```

This will automatically redraw the chart and update the data: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zqhavLz9/1/)

Or you can use `this.series[0].isDirty = true` before calling `redraw`:

```
load: function () {
                this.series[0].data[1].y=7.5;
                this.series[0].isDirty = true;
                this.redraw();
            }
```

Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zqhavLz9/2/)